What causes are there for Google not to be able to access my website
I have a server with multiple websites on it.
One of these websites loads fine in all browsers and is successfully loaded by any third party tools (such as DNS testers, HTTP header testers, SSL Query labs certificate testers, etc.)
But Google uniformly fails to load the website according to what Google says; Adsense is disabled because it can't see the website, AMP tester can't reach the website, I am unable to verify the website on Google webmaster tools.
Edit: To clarify; Google can't see the DNS (it loads the TXT SPF record despite the google DNS TXT record being first and despite multiple TXT records being totally valid on DNS)
The only Google aspect that seems to reach the website is PageSpeed Web Dev:
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/
All other parts of Google can't seem to see it.
Non issues:

I have checked the site on Google itself and some pages on the website are displaying which implies that it is not on a penalty.

I have put tracking on place on the website which shows that when asking Google to access the site (such as through the AMP tester tool here) that the site successfully connects, according to my server.

Various other sites such as MX Toolbox, SSL Qualys Test, SecurityHeaders , DNSinfo , etc. etc. all load the website without issue or delay.

I have checked the Apache httpconf and htaccess and see nothing singling out Google.

No Google IPs are blocked on the server level.


This is not a temporary issue.
Help please!
I don't know where else to look as to why Google seems to be blocked on the website? Google feedback is very vague and non-specific saying "can't access the website" or on the Webmaster Verify dialogue saying:
"Could not find your site. Please check that you provided the correct URL for your property."
Any help appreciated. How to show Google the website does indeed exist... or what other aspects should I check to see if Google is being filtered out somehow by my server?

Does PageSpeed Insights show any issues under the SEO section?

The list of possible reasons is huge. The list of probable reasons is a lot smaller: DNS propagation.

What does using Google's URL inspection tool for a live URL say?

@StephenOstermiller I can't use it. The inspection tool requires me to verify my property before inspecting it but I can't verify it due to the above. Bit of a catch-22.

@symcbean I totally get that re probable reasons, but I've managed to exclude quite a few reasons . I've checked DNS propagation but that should be fine (I've already had a few days exploring this issue).

@RichardB it says  Performance: 85 | Accessibility: 83 | Best Practices: 100 | SEO: 92

Why does it say SEO isn't 100%?  I'm asking because it would list potential crawling issues like robots.txt blocking Google.

@RichardB there are two links on the page for lightbox gallery which it claims are not crawlable because the links are javascript references for lightbox 2.

Do you use a CDN?

@RichardB no. Having tweaked these links SEO score is 100 on both mobile and desktop views on pagespeed insights.

Use the DNS method to verify your property in Google Search Console.

@StephenOstermiller yes, as stated the DNS method doesn't work

What are the NS records for this domain at the DNS registrar?  What are the NS records at your DNS host?

@StephenOstermiller I would have thought if there was a DNS issue then the rest of the internet would have highlighted this, but that's not the case.

If DNS verification isn't working, there is a DNS issue.  Please add your DNS records to your question.

@StephenOstermiller correction, NS records show "ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com." because the domain holds an email address that diverts to an existing google mail account.

When you implement the TXT, A, CNAME and AAAA records, you are doing so in the googledomains.com interface?  Is Google domains both your registrar and your DNS host then?

@StephenOstermiller no the DNS is entirely separate from Google. You can see the DNS settings here. Thank you. The purpose is that client@their_address.com wants to be able to handle emails via their Google account. Their domain DNS was previously under Google but now it is not.

It sounds like you don't have your DNS host configured correctly then.  Your NS records at your registrar have to point to the name servers given to you by your DNS host.  Otherwise they are not your DNS host.  It sounds like you have Google domains configured to be your DNS host, but you want some other DNS host.  If you want help fixing it, you need to add lots of info about your DNS records to your question.  Probably including the actual domain name so that we can help test.

Thanks for the info. Will need to converse with the client as they run their Google side of things.
